# loopComplete function called repeatedly in Anime.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, animation, anime.js

I call my animated element as follows:

```
 emdrSpawnElement = anime({
            targets: '#alternate-main .el',
            translateX: destination,
            direction: 'alternate',
            loop: true,
            easing: selectedEasing,
            duration: emdrSpawnElementSpeed,
            autoPlay:false,
            loopBegin: function (anim) { },
            loopComplete: function (anim) {
                if(trackingPassesActive == true)
                {
                    totalPasses++;
                    if((totalPasses % 2) == 0)
                    {
                        passesDisplayed++;
                        document.getElementById("passes-count-2").innerText = passesDisplayed.toString();
                        console.log(passesDisplayed);
                    }
                }


                clearInterval(switchDirectionSoundPlayer);
                switchDirectionSoundPlay();
            }
        });
```

My interface contains a slider to change the speed of the element. Every time the slider is moved, the code listed above calls again.

**My problem: the loopComplete function is running as if every time I change the slider, a new anime element is created without deleting the old one. The result is the loopComplete function being called many times, increasing every time I change the slider.**

My goal is to stop repeat calls to the loopComplete function. How can I remove the anime element every time I want to change its speed? I only want the loopComplete function to be calling for one anime element at a time. Much love to anyone who can share some wisdom on this subject.

Comment: I would be useful to see the entirety of the file.

Comment: Hey Brandon! The entirety of the file is several thousand lines long, but I have narrowed the problem down to the loopComplete element calling too many times. It appears when I redefine the emdrSpawnElement variable, it keeps the loopComplete function running from when it was initially defined. I'm trying to prevent this from happening and only have the loopComplete run for the most recent iteration of emdrSpawnElement.

Comment: You should recreate the issue in a CodeSandbox or something then. No one is going to be able to help you without more to go on. 

https://codesandbox.io/s/jquery-7v3un